# ¿Cómo quitar los márgenes en listas de Bootstrap en Wordpress?

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap, wordpress

Estoy realizando una plantilla Wordpress usando el Framework Bootstrap 3.x, al adaptarlo a WP las listas `li` me las muestra con márgenes, además de que también perjudica a la manera de mostrar las categorías en cada artículo.

Les muestro algunas capturas para que vean cómo está quedando:

[image: Asi me muestra la categoría en Wordpress]
[image: Asi me muestra las listas de links por ejemplo]

¿Existe alguna manera de quitarle esos márgenes en las listas para que se vean de forma correcta?

Comment: Nos puedes mostrar el HTML/CSS que estas usando? "Quitar los margenes en las listas" no es suficiente para poder ayudarte

Comment: Hola y bienvenido! para poder recibir ayuda, edita la pregunta y agrega el pedazo de HTML y cualquier CSS personalizado que lo afecte. De la imagen no se puede deducir como lo hiciste. Salu2!

Answer (score 2):

Una **solución con Bootstrap** sería hacer uso del par de clases que hacen que las listas no tengan estilos o márgenes:

- [`list-unstyled`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#unstyled): elimina el estilo de la lista (`list-style`) y el márgen de los elementos. Es importante que sepas que ese estilo sólo se aplica a los hijos directos; si tienes una sublista, tendrás que añadir la clase `list-unstyled` para esa también.
- [`list-inline`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#inline): elimina el estilo de la lista (`list-style`) y el márgen de los elementos, aunque añade un poco de *padding*. Como indica el nombre de la clase, convierte la lista a *inline* y es muy útil para listas horizontales como en los menús o las categorías de artículos.

Y si quieres que sigan teniendo estilo de lista (el guioncito o icono que aparece junto a cada elemento), puedes definir su propia clase con la propiedad [`list-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/list-style) y añadirla en combinación con las ya mencionadas.

---

Otra **solución independiente de Bootstrap** sería definir tus propios estilos con un margin y padding izquierdo de cero para la lista (`ul` y/o `ol`) y los elementos de la lista (`li`):

```
ul, li {
    padding-left:0;
    margin-left:0;
}
```

Puedes ser más específico si quieres y poner sólo las listas que te interesen (indicando clases o identificadores). Si eso no funciona, puede ser porque algún estilo de Bootstrap (u otro fichero) tenga precedencia sobre el estilo y puedes usar el modificador `!important` para darle prioridad a tus estilos:

```
ul, li {
    padding-left:0 !important;
    margin-left:0 !important;
}
```